# Looking for ideas/references/keywords: adaptive-parameter-control of a search algorithm (online-learning)

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, heuristics, reinforcement-learning

I'm looking for ideas/experiences/references/keywords regarding an **adaptive-parameter-control** of **search algorithm** parameters (**online-learning**) in combinatorial-optimization.

A bit more detail:

I have a framework, which is responsible for optimizing a hard combinatorial-optimization-problem. This is done with the help of some "small heuristics" which are used in an iterative manner (large-neighborhood-search; ruin-and-recreate-approach). Every algorithm of these "small heuristics" is taking some external parameters, which are controlling the heuristic-logic in some extent (at the moment: just random values; some kind of noise; diversify the search).

Now i want to have a control-framework for choosing these parameters in a convergence-improving way, as general as possible, so that later additions of new heuristics are possible without changing the parameter-control.

There are at least two general decisions to make:

- A: Choose the algorithm-pair (one destroy- and one rebuild-algorithm) which is used in the next iteration.
- B: Choose the random parameters of the algorithms.

The only feedback is an evaluation-function of the new-found-solution. That leads me to the topic of **reinforcement-learning**. Is that the right direction?

Not really a learning-like-behavior, but the simplistic ideas at the moment are:

- A: A roulette-wheel-selection according to some performance-value collected during the iterations (near past is more valued than older ones).
  So if heuristic 1 did find all the new global best solutions -> high probability of choosing this one.
- B: No idea yet. Maybe it's possible to use some non-uniform random values in the range (0,1) and i'm collecting some momentum of the changes.
  So if heuristic 1 last time used alpha = 0.3 and found no new best solution, then used 0.6 and found a new best solution -> there is a momentum towards 1
  -> next random value is likely to be bigger than 0.3. Possible problems: *oscillation*!

Things to remark:
- The parameters needed for good convergence of one specific algorithm can change dramatically -> maybe more diversify-operations needed at the beginning,    more intensify-operations needed at the end.
- There is a possibility of good synergistic-effects in a specific pair of destroy-/rebuild-algorithm (sometimes called: coupled neighborhoods). How would one recognize something like that? Is that still in the reinforcement-learning-area?
- The different algorithms are controlled by a different number of parameters (some taking 1, some taking 3).

Any ideas, experiences, references (papers), keywords (ml-topics)?
If there are ideas regarding the decision of (b) in a **offline-learning**-manner. Don't hesitate to mention that.

Thanks for all your input.

Sascha

Answer (score 1):

You have a set of parameter variables which you use to control your set of algorithms. Selection of your algorithms is just another variable.

One approach you might like to consider is to evolve your 'parameter space' using a genetic algorithm. In short, GA uses an analogue of the processes of natural selection to successively breed ever better solutions.

You will need to develop an encoding scheme to represent your parameter space as a string, and then create a large population of candidate solutions as your starting generation. The genetic algorithm itself takes the fittest solutions in your set and then applies various genetic operators to them (mutation, reproduction etc.) to breed a better set which then become the next generation.

The most difficult part of this process is developing an appropriate fitness function: something to quantitatively measure the quality of a given parameter space. Your search problem may be too complex to measure for each candidate in the population, so you will need a proxy model function which might be as hard to develop as the ideal solution itself.

Without understanding more of what you've written it's hard to see whether this approach is viable or not. GA is usually well suited to multi-variable optimisation problems like this, but it's not a silver bullet. For a reference start with Wikipedia.

Comment: I was aware of the general technique of Evolutionary Algorithms, but i missed this simple idea of a parameter-search space. I will have a look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like *hyper heuristics* which you're trying to do. Try looking for that keyword.

In [Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner) (open source, java) I have support for tabu search and simulated annealing out the box.
I haven't implemented the ruin-and-recreate-approach (yet), but that should be easy, although I am not expecting better results. Challenge: Prove me wrong and fork it and add it and beat me in the examples.
Hyper heuristics are on my TODO list.